# How to refresh page and send request with some data via jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing dynamic dropdown menu but I have problem to keep it after page refreshing.

I use maybe old way and if user choose some option in first select, I am sending ajax request to php page and show options on current page in second select.

I store all values of fields via localstorage, but problem is that selects (inputs) added dynamically by ajax are not visible on load of page.

So I decide to send my data to php page directly in request sent after refreshing.

My code is something like this:

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        // Send cat id to add.php to change select options in html according to cat id
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add.php',
            headers: {"X-Test-Header": "test-value"}
        });
    })
```

I am attaching image flow.
[image]

So my problem is that if **I refresh page and do not send SUBCAT_ID** then **Filters section is not created in ADD.PHP**.

I want to know way **how to send SUBCAT_ID in request sent by page refreshing action**.

This is my code for dropdown menu:

```
    /* SELECT REPLACED BY DIV JS */

    var select = $('.add-item__select').hide(); // Hide original select options

    // Replace each select by div
    select.each(function() {
        var selectVal = $(this).find('.add-item__select-main').text(),
            name = $(this).attr('name');

        newDropdownDiv = $('<input class="add-item__input-select" name="' + name + '" placeholder="' + selectVal + '" readonly required><i class="arrow down"></i></input>')
            .insertAfter($(this))
            .css({paddingLeft: '0.3em', cursor: 'pointer'});
    });

    /* SELECT CATEGORIES AND FILTER CONNECTIONS*/

    // Declare variables
    var inputSelectCat = $("input[name=category]"),
        inputSelectSubCat = $("input[name=subcategory]"),
        section = $('.section'),
        arrowDown = inputSelectSubCat.next(),
        catNameOld;

    if (inputSelectSubCat.val() === '') {
        inputSelectSubCat
            .addClass('stop') // Defaultly setup subcategory input as disable until category is not chosen
            .next().hide(); // Defaultly hide arrowdown of input subcategory until category is not chosen
    }

    // Do not hide placehoder after focusin
    inputSelectSubCat.on('focusin', function() {
        inputSelectSubCat.addClass('black-color-placeholder');
    })

    // Get old value of input
    inputSelectCat.on('focusin', function() {
        catNameOld = $(this).val();
    })

    // If change value of category then change options of subcategory
    inputSelectSubCat.on('focusout', function() {

        var subCatNameNew = $(this).val();

        // Send cat id to add.php to change select options in html according to cat id
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                subcat_name_js: subCatNameNew
            }
        }).done(function(html) {
            var filterOptionsNew = $(html).find('#section-filters').find('.add-item__form-data'),
                filterOptionsCurrent = $('#section-filters');

            // Replace current select by new one - data for dropdown list are loaded from select
            filterOptionsCurrent.html(filterOptionsNew);

            // Replace each select by div
            var filtersSelect = $('#section-filters').find('select');

            // Create dropdown list for all new inputs in filter section
            filtersSelect.each(function() {
                var selectVal = $(this).find('.add-item__select-main').text(),
                    name = $(this).attr('name');

                newDropdownDiv = $('<input class="add-item__input-select" name="' + name + '" placeholder="' + selectVal + '" readonly required><i class="arrow down"></i></input>')
                    .insertAfter($(this))
                    .css({paddingLeft: '0.3em', cursor: 'pointer'});
            });

            // Show filters section
            $('#filters, #section-filters').show();

            // Hide all select elements inside filters section
            $('#section-filters').find('select').hide();

            // Count all added fields
            var filtersInputs = $('#section-filters').find('.add-item__input-select');

            filtersInputs.each(function() {

                // Count inputs
                if ( ($(this).val() === "") && $(this).is(':required') && !localStorage.getItem('allFieldsCount') ) {
                    allFieldsCount += 1;
                }
            })

            // Save modified field count in local storage
            localStorage.setItem('allFieldsCount', allFieldsCount);
        })
    });

    // Allow subcategory input always if category is chosen and value is not empty
    $( window ).on('load', function() {
         console.log(inputSelectCat.val());
        if (inputSelectCat.val() !== '') {
            arrowDown.show();
            inputSelectSubCat.removeClass('stop black-color-placeholder');
        }
    })

    //localStorage.clear();

    // If change value of category then change options of subcategory
    inputSelectCat.on('focusout', function() {

        var catNameNew = $(this).val(),
            arrowDown = inputSelectSubCat.next();

        // Send cat id to add.php to change select options in html according to cat id
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                cat_name_js: catNameNew
            }
        }).done(function(html) {

            var subCatMenuNew = $(html).find('select[name=subcategory]'),
                subCatMenuCurrent = $('#section-info').find('select[name=subcategory]');

            // Replace current select by new one - data for dropdown list are loaded from select
            subCatMenuCurrent.html(subCatMenuNew);
        })

        // Allow subcategory input always if category is chosen and value is not empty
        if (catNameNew !== '') {
            arrowDown.show();
            inputSelectSubCat.removeClass('stop black-color-placeholder');
        }

        // If different category is chosen, then clear input value
        if (catNameOld !== catNameNew) {
            inputSelectSubCat.val('');
        }

    });

    /* SELECT REPLACED BY DIV JS */

    var inputSelect = $('.add-item__input-select');

    // Add new div with options after click on select
    section.on('click','.add-item__input-select', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var currentNewDropdown = $(this).next(),
            currentInput = $(this),
            currentSelect = $(this).parent().find('select');

        // Do not allow to add dropdown list for subcategory if it has class 'stop'
        if ( !currentInput.hasClass('stop')) {

            // Check if new div dropdown already exists if not add new one
            if ( !currentNewDropdown.hasClass('add-item__custom-select-box') ) {
                var newDropdown = $('<div/>') // create new div element
                    .addClass('add-item__custom-select-box') // with class NewDropdown
                    .insertAfter($(this)); // and append it to page
            }
        }

        // If select was already clicked on, then do not create new dropdown list
        if ( !currentInput.hasClass('added') ) {

            // Check each option value and attach it to new dropdown as div
            currentSelect.find('option').each(function(index, element) {

                var option = $(this); // this is the option from the original select
                    currentNewDropdown = $(this).parent().next();

                // If option is disabled do not append it to new dropdown list
                if (!option.prop('disabled')) {
                    // Create dropdown list as copy of original select list
                    var newOption = $('<div/>') // create new div element
                        .addClass('add-item__custom-select-box-items') // with class NewDropdown-item
                        .html(option.html()) // copy content from original option
                        .data('value', option.val()) // copy value from original option
                        .appendTo(newDropdown); // append it to the new dropdown
                }
            })

            // Show new dropdown options after click on select
            if ( !currentInput.hasClass('stop')) {
                currentNewDropdown = $(this).next();
                currentNewDropdown.show();
                currentInput.addClass('added');
            }
        }

    });

    // Remove dropdown list if focusout without value chosen
    section.on('focusout','.add-item__input-select', function() {
        var newDropdown = $(this).parent().find('.add-item__custom-select-box'),
            inputValue = $(this).val();

        newDropdown.remove();
        inputSelect.removeClass('added');
        inputSelect.addClass('black-text');
    });

    // Add value of clicked element to original option
    section.on('mousedown','.add-item__custom-select-box-items', function() {
        var clickedOptionText = $(this).text(), // Get choosen otion text
            clickedOptionVal = $(this).data('value'), // Get choosen option value
            currentInput = $(this).parent().prev(),
            currentSelect = $(this).parent().parent().find('select'),
            newDropdown = $(this).parent();

        currentSelect.val(clickedOptionVal); // Set up value of original select
        currentInput.val(clickedOptionText); // Show chosen value in input
        newDropdown.remove();
        currentInput.removeClass('added');
        currentInput.addClass('black-text');
    });
```

Plus code for localstorage:

```
    /* SAVE FORM DATA TO LOCAL STORAGE - presistent - saved until submit is not clicked  */

    // The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page for ex. page refresh
    $(window).on('unload', function() {

        // Save values of form fields to local storage
        $(':file, :checkbox, select, textarea, input').each(function() {

            // Due to JS added input instead of select, need to get value from input + add to storage just checked items
            if ( !$(this).hasClass('add-item__select') && !$(this).is(':checkbox') ) {

                // Save value of field to local storage
                localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());

            } else if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {

                // Save just name of checkbox which is checked
                localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());

            }
        })
    });

    // Get values form local storage if page is refreshed
    $(window).on('load', function() {

        // Save values of form fields to local storage
        $(':file, :checkbox, select, textarea, input').each(function() {

            // Set values for input elements
            if ( !$(this).hasClass('add-item__select') && ( !$(this).is(':checkbox' ) && !$(this).is(':file') ) ) {
                // Get value of field
                fieldValue = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name'));

                // Show value of field if fieldValue is not empty
                if (fieldValue.length !== 0) {
                    // Fill value of element by value from from localstorage - all filled fileds must have class counted to be not conted again
                    $(this).val(fieldValue).addClass('black-text counted');

                    // Add label, bcz it is checked just on focusout event
                    $('<label class="add-item__form-label-JS">' + $(this).attr('placeholder') + '</label>').insertBefore($(this));
                    $('.add-item__form-label-JS').css({color: '#888'});
                }

            // Done action just for checkbox
            } else if ( $(this).is(':checkbox') ) {

                // Get value of field
                fieldValue = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name'));

                // All filled fileds must have class counted to be not conted again
                // If chekcbox name is same as saved in local storage then set as checked
                if ( fieldValue === $(this).val() ) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('counted');
                }

                // Remove checkbox value in localstorage each time - bcz of change checked checkboxes
                localStorage.removeItem(fieldValue);

            }
        })
    });
```

**If POST data are not sent in same request BUT in request after page refresh THEN code for filling data from localstorage is not working for filter section*** bcz it was not visible during loading.

Thanks

Comment: if I understand correctly, you have a second dropdown that will change its options when an option gets picked on the first dropdown. And your problem is restoring the same options on that 2nd dropdown when the page gets loaded with value prefilled. It's not clear how you populate the dropdowns anyway I think you should, on document ready, read the 1st dropdown value and trigger the loading of the options in the second dropdown ***before*** setting the value on the 2nd one. Anyway it's hard to understand the question. Maybe if you add more details

Comment: Diego D
I added image flow for better understanding. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: the problem is that when you reload the page I think you should have the values of how you filled the form previously, stored somewhere like in the session storage. Then at document load, take those values and automatically fill the form one field at a time, firing each time the event that will trigger the addition of parts of the document not shown. But here I'm giving things for granted and proceeding on my assumptions

Comment: I mean trying to better decode your picture.. it seems like you reload the whole page just because you changed the select option in the first dropdown. Isn't it overkill? shouldn't you just fetch the options for the second dropdown using an ajax request? If those are the condition, when you reload the page you'll have no request parameters sent and of course it will reload from scratch. If you want to remain with that scenario, I think you need to add a logic client side that will listen for change on any input and will save the state

Comment: No I want to show filter section even after user refresh the page. But it is working just if POST data are sent in request to add.php evoked by page refresh.

Comment: exactly. But as you also know, if you refresh the page, there are not parameters sent. So if you want to keep your current system as is, but yet implement a feature that will find if any form was filled before, you need to keep track of every input change on your form, save them in session storage, and query them every time you load the page with no parameters. Such scenario will supposedly force the reload of the page as soon as the automatic procedure will change the first dropdown. As long as that's how it works now

Comment: Noe, I understsnd. So maybe I can fill all fields on page load and then do ajax request on page load event which will show all inputs for filter section and then in the same step fill these inputs from localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

***I think you want a second dropdown option on the base of the first selection.

To send an ajax call on the change value of the dropdown, use jquery on the change event***

```
 $('#FirstdropdownID').('change', function() {
  // Send an AJAX request when First dropdown is changed/select
 // Send an AJAX request to the add.php page
$.ajax({
  url: 'add.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    catId: $('#FirstdropdownID').val()
  },
  success: function(response) {
     // for the current scenario
     // Update the select box with the new options
     $('#secondDropdownID').html(response);
   }
  });
});
  

** code for Php File add.php**


<?php
  // Get the cat id from the request
  $catId = $_POST['catId'];

  // Generate the HTML for the new select options
  

$optionsHtml = '';
  foreach ($catOptions as $option) {
    $optionsHtml .= "<option value='".$option['value']."'>".$option['label']." 
   </option>";
  }

  // Return the HTML to the client
  echo $optionsHtml;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry if the question is written not very clearly, This part I already have done, but I have problem with sending POST data to add.php after page refresh (in the same request started by page refreshing action).

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get your point. 
"I want to know a way how to send SUBCAT_ID in the request sent by page refreshing action."
Is you have SUBCAT_ID (value ) when the window refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. I have same code processed during two different events.

1. after option is chosen -> **focusout event**

```
    // If change value of category then change options of subcategory
    inputSelectSubCat.on('focusout', function() {

        var subCatNameNew = $(this).val();

        // Send cat id to add.php to change select options in html according to cat id
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                subcat_name_js: subCatNameNew
            }
        }).done(function(html) {
            var filterOptionsNew = $(html).find('#section-filters').find('.add-item__form-data'),
                filterOptionsCurrent = $('#section-filters');

            // Replace current select by new one - data for dropdown list are loaded from select
            filterOptionsCurrent.html(filterOptionsNew);

            // Replace each select by div
            var filtersSelect = $('#section-filters').find('select');

            // Create dropdown list for all new inputs in filter section
            filtersSelect.each(function() {
                var selectVal = $(this).find('.add-item__select-main').text(),
                    name = $(this).attr('name');

                newDropdownDiv = $('<input class="add-item__input-select" name="' + name + '" placeholder="' + selectVal + '" readonly required><i class="arrow down"></i></input>')
                    .insertAfter($(this))
                    .css({paddingLeft: '0.3em', cursor: 'pointer'});
            });

            // Show filters section
            $('#filters, #section-filters').show();

            // Hide all select elements inside filters section
            $('#section-filters').find('select').hide();

            // Count all added fields
            var filtersInputs = $('#section-filters').find('.add-item__input-select');

            filtersInputs.each(function() {

                // Count inputs
                if ( ($(this).val() === "") && $(this).is(':required') && !localStorage.getItem('allFieldsCount') ) {
                    allFieldsCount += 1;
                }
            })

            // Save modified field count in local storage
            localStorage.setItem('allFieldsCount', allFieldsCount);

        })
    });
```

2. after page is loaded -> **load event**
   I read value of select after refresh page from localstorage -> send to add.php -> and show filter section with filled data

```
    $( window ).on('load', function() {
    // If change value of category then change options of subcategory

        var subCatNameNew = localStorage.getItem('subcategory');

        // Send cat id to add.php to change select options in html according to cat id
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                subcat_name_js: subCatNameNew
            }
        }).done(function(html) {
            var filterOptionsNew = $(html).find('#section-filters').find('.add-item__form-data'),
                filterOptionsCurrent = $('#section-filters');

            // Replace current select by new one - data for dropdown list are loaded from select
            filterOptionsCurrent.html(filterOptionsNew);

            // Replace each select by div
            var filtersSelect = $('#section-filters').find('select');

            // Create dropdown list for all new inputs in filter section
            filtersSelect.each(function() {
                var selectVal = $(this).find('.add-item__select-main').text(),
                    name = $(this).attr('name');

                newDropdownDiv = $('<input class="add-item__input-select" name="' + name + '" placeholder="' + selectVal + '" readonly required><i class="arrow down"></i></input>')
                    .insertAfter($(this))
                    .css({paddingLeft: '0.3em', cursor: 'pointer'});
            });

            // Show filters section
            $('#filters, #section-filters').show();

            // Hide all select elements inside filters section
            $('#section-filters').find('select').hide();

            // Count all added fields
            var filtersInputs = $('#section-filters').find('.add-item__input-select');

            filtersInputs.each(function() {

                // Count inputs
                if ( ($(this).val() === "") && $(this).is(':required') && !localStorage.getItem('allFieldsCount') ) {
                    allFieldsCount += 1;
                }
            })

            // Save modified field count in local storage
            localStorage.setItem('allFieldsCount', allFieldsCount);

            // Save values of form fields to local storage
            $(':file, :checkbox, select, textarea, input').each(function() {

                // Set values for input elements
                if ( !$(this).hasClass('add-item__select') && ( !$(this).is(':checkbox' ) && !$(this).is(':file') ) ) {
                    // Get value of field
                    fieldValue = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name'));

                    // Show value of field if fieldValue is not empty
                    if (fieldValue.length !== 0) {
                        // Fill value of element by value from from localstorage - all filled fileds must have class counted to be not conted again
                        $(this).val(fieldValue).addClass('black-text counted');

                        // Add label, bcz it is checked just on focusout event
                        $('<label class="add-item__form-label-JS">' + $(this).attr('placeholder') + '</label>').insertBefore($(this));
                        $('.add-item__form-label-JS').css({color: '#888'});
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

I would appreciate if you know some better, nicer solution to write it as answer,

Thank you